# Sign in users with OIDC on Google Identity Platform. What is the Issuer-URL?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-identity

I use a GKE and a [ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine?hl=de) for user authentication. It works well with Keycloak, but now I am trying to do the same with Google Identity Platform and Firebase.

I created a OpenID Connect provider with a client ID and a client secret of an oauth-client. But what is the issuer url? [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc):

> The provider's Issuer. This should look something like https://example.com. Identity Platform uses this URL to locate the OIDC discovery document (typically found at /.well-known/openid-configuration), which specifies the provider's OAuth endpoints and public keys.

The services on my GKE have no DNS. Is it required to continue?
I also have to use that Issuer url in the esp. Do I need Firebase?

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to use ESP with Google Identity Platform (GIP)?  And  you are also registering a provider with GIP?   What do you mean by `I created a OpenID Connect provider ...`?

Comment: Does that help? https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere years later this helped a lot.